# wordpress template layout single.php

Tags: wordpress, templates

I need to custom single.php template in my wordpress template. 
In my single.php I have this line

My new template need to show post image, post date, post text.

How I can do it?

Thanks

Comment: You have to learn php or use a plugin that does that for you. Google around. http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/create-custom-single-post-templates-for-specific-posts-or-sections-in-wordpress/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google could have easily told you how this is done, but because I'm here I will help.

First, learn the [WordPress Loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop).

Open your single.php template and paste the following:

```
<?php 
    if ( have_posts() ) {
        while ( have_posts() ) {
            the_post(); 

            // Post Image
            the_post_thumbnail();

            // Post Date
            the_date();

            // The Post Content
            the_content();

        } // end while
    } // end if
?>
```

Then read up on the functions used:

[the_post_thumbnail()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post_thumbnail/)

[the_date()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_date)

[the_content()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_content/)

Comment: Thank! Sorry but I'm newbie with wordpress and I start to read same thinks.

Comment: Try removing the image using the answer here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/162165/70417

Comment: Finally, my solutions is remove image from single.php using : wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/162165/70417. If featured image exists, I show via php code. Thanks!